# Query post for posts from the beginning

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know why but when I want to display the posts with comment opened, it shows posts which are among the last 10 posts (depend how much is in READING menu), so posts which are in the first page.

My code :

```
        <?php
// The Query
query_posts( $args );

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php 
$PostID = get_the_ID();

if (comments_open( $post_id )) { ?>
<?php p2_load_entry(); ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

This is my file :

```
<?php
/**
 * Static page template.
  Template Name: test
 *
 * @package P2
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<ul id="postlist">
<?php
query_posts( $args );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php 
$PostID = get_the_ID();
if (comments_open( $post_id )) { ?><?php p2_load_entry(); ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
</ul>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: It's not. I made a mistake : I wanted to write query

Comment: What's the query being used?

Comment: I use Query because it's a specific page template

Comment: The issue could be in the query you are running, what is the query? We are missing information and can't help with out, among other things, the query.

Comment: $args is for nothing. I've may made a mistake from the biginning.

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting $PostID and then calling $post_id?

Comment: Actually not but it's change nothing. I found something on stackoverflow regarding my problem. It's because Query display only posts from the static page. Is it right ?